# PHPUnitLogger::flush() must be compatible

Tags: composer-php, phpunit

I want to use PHPUnit in a PHP project developed in Eclipse (4.7.3a)

I first installed PHPUnit via Composer (the list of packages is below as described in composer.json)

I then installed the PHP Developpement Tools and in particular PHPUnit Support (6.1.0.20180828281524)

When I then try to run PHPUnit, I get the message

```
Fatal error: Declaration of PHPUnitLogger::flush() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Util\Util\Printer::flush(): void in /private/var/folders/mp/_jmfjcd91jdbjjrx6w23600h0000gn/T/phpunit_printer/PHPUnitLogger.php on line 33
```

What is the installation error?

Thank you.

Composer.json :

```
{
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Adlc\\Objects\\" : "lib-src/objects/",
            "Adlc\\Db\\" : "lib-src/db/"
        }
    },
    "name" : "Adlc/V2-BP-library",
    "type" : "library",
    "description" : "Shared code for V2",
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=7.1",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php" : "~3.81",
        "lcobucci/jwt" : "~3.2",
        "robthree/twofactorauth" : "~1.6",
        "monolog/monolog" : "~1.24",
        "maxbanton/cwh" : "~1.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "~7.5"
    }
}
```